# User program compiled with arm-linux-xxx-gcc runs on a x86 machine?

Tags: linux, gcc, cross-compiling

I cross-compiled hello.c with arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc

```
>arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -static -o hello hello.c -g
```

I've checked the format of ./hello, it's an arm user program!

```
>file ./hello
hello: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=d56f37000fa4ae28889f3c785ed55b1dd48bdda7, not stripped
```

, and qemu-arm is able to run ./hello

```
>qemu-arm ./hello
hello, world
```

Then, why can I run hello directly with ./hello

```
>./hello
hello, world
```

Why and how this happened?

---

2017/3/19 edited:

I've tested that x86_64 user program is not runable with qemu-arm

```
> gcc -o hello_x86 hello.c
> qemu-arm hello_x86
hello_x86: Invalid ELF image for this architecture
```

---

2017/3/19 edited:

I remove gdb part in this article. gdb is not function correctly here. And the assembly I saw is NOT from this program.

Comment: Have you been playing with [binfmt_misc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binfmt_misc)? Does `file hello` still show ARM? Run `pwd`, and make sure your paths are still where you think.

Comment: I know nothing about binfmt_misc until you mentioned it. Is it possible that the elf contains x86 and arm at the same time?

Comment: Your system might be configured (perhaps with [binfmt_misc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binfmt_misc) ...) to run `qemu-arm` on every ELF file for ARM.

Comment: How could I disable this feature?

Answer (score 0):

in fact i needed to link software for the adress 0x0010000 to be executed a guest code on host machine because The QEMU emulator is written especially to emulate Linux guest systems; for this reason its startup procedure is implemented specifically: the -kernel option loads a binary file (usually a Linux kernel) inside the system memory starting at address 0x00010000. The emulator starts the execution at address 0x00000000, so we need to place our binary in the correct adress

i follow this [tutorial](https://balau82.wordpress.com/2010/02/28/hello-world-for-bare-metal-arm-using-qemu/) and it works for me